# Creating simple plugin, my first plugin run in to a bug

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, syntax

[A JS Fiddle of the plugin working](http://jsfiddle.net/KmjpV/2/)

A contraction plugin for numerical values (ST,RD,TH).

I have been playing around with creating my own plugin, at the moment I'm just getting used to the syntax etc, this is just my playing with a script I needed and found today.

ok - my plugin should add th, st, rd etc on the end of any number with a span.num wrapped around it, the problem is for every number i need to call the plugin each time?

so I have two numbers, i need to give them both unique class names and then call my plugin (see fiddle)

**my question**: is it possible to only use one class name many times, and get back different results for each?

I'm thankful in advance for any replies and all apologies for my English today - brain fried!

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".num1").simpleContraction();
        $(".num2").simpleContraction();
    });


    (function( $ ){
        $.fn.simpleContraction = function() {

          var num = this.text();
          var len = num.length, last_char = num.charAt(len - 1), abbrev

            if (len == 2 && num.charAt(0) == '1') {
                abbrev = 'th'
            } else {
                if (last_char == '1') {
                    abbrev = 'st'
                } else if (last_char == '2') {
                    abbrev = 'nd'
                } else if (last_char == '3') {
                    abbrev = 'rd'
                } else {
                    abbrev = 'th'
                }
            }

            return this.html(num+abbrev);
        };
    })( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap a `this.each()` block around your code so that each element in the jQuery collection is processed in turn:

```
$.fn.simpleContraction = function() {
    return this.each(function() { 
        // NB: "this" is now a DOM element - wrap if required
        var $this = $(this);
        ...
    });
}
```

That said, I wouldn't actually write this as a true plugin - it'll have really nasty side effects if called on the wrong elements.

Instead, you can take advantage of the fact that `.text` can be passed a function that is passed the original text out of an element, and replaces it with the return value of that function:

```
$.simpleContraction = function(index, text) {
    // parse "text" etc
    ... 
    return num + abbrev;
}

// call on required elements
$('span.num').text($.simpleContraction);
```

The advantage of this approach is that it separates the DOM manipulation from the string manipulation, and gives you a function that can be used on any string variable, and not just ones stored in the DOM.

Comment: thank you for you in depth answer ill have a gander tomorrow, much appreciated though!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to loop through each of the items that the plugin was invoked on:

```
$.fn.plopPlugin = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        // do your stuff on a single item
        // no need to return antyhing from within this function
        // unless you want to continue (return true)
        // or break (return false)
    });
};
```

So... http://jsfiddle.net/KmjpV/3/

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.plopPlugin = function() {
      return this.each(function(){
        var num = $(this).text();
        var len = num.length, last_char = num.charAt(len - 1), abbrev

        if (len == 2 && num.charAt(0) == '1') {
            abbrev = 'th'
        } else {
            if (last_char == '1') {
                abbrev = 'st'
            } else if (last_char == '2') {
                abbrev = 'nd'
            } else if (last_char == '3') {
                abbrev = 'rd'
            } else {
                abbrev = 'th'
            }
        }
        alert(num+abbrev)
        $(this).html(num+abbrev);
      });
    };
})( jQuery );
```